# How to find the reason for XAMARIN App crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wrote an App with XAMARIN.
Currently I test the App with Android emulator.

Sometimes it happens, if I start debuggin of the App, I get a crash with Message:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf8Fm.png)

This crashes happens before the UI in emulator shows any view. I just have a white screen if the crash happens.

Unfortunately, there is no information for this message.
Is there a chance to get any information which line of code raised this error?
Can I get any Stack trace ore something else?
Im new in debugging with visual studio.

Comment: [Tell debugger to break when exception thrown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown).

Comment: What does the `Sometimes it happens` mean? Did the code work before? We get this error from the code when access a null object normally. Have you check your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS, try this:

- Go to menu `Debug > Windows > Exception Settings` or type `Ctrl-Alt-E`.
- Tick the box on the line that says "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".
- Start a Debug session (F5).
- VS will now break on *any* exception that occurs, even the ones that have a `try...catch`.
- You may need to ignore a few exceptions (press F5 to proceed) to get to the actual location of your problem.
- Analyze the problem and write a fix.
- To reset VS back to its normal behavior, right click on the line "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and select "Restore Defaults".